# How to create a TIFF file from TIFF image data

Tags: java, image, tiff

I have got several files that contains a specific header follows by TIFF image data.
How can I write those TIFF image data into a TIFF file ?
Thanks for your help.

EDIT : Here's what I tested :

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
is.skip(252);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(is);
File fileOut = new File(fileOutPath);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage,"TIFF", fileOut);
```

I skip the specific header of the file (252Bytes) to get the Tiff Image data bytes.
But the bufferedImage is null so I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null! exception.

In resume, I have a TIFF file without a TIFF header. The TIFF header has been replace by a specific one but the image bytes are exactly the same as in a TIFF file.

EDIT :
Thanks to haraldK, I can finally create a TIFF header. But I can't open the image, maybe it is because of the compression : "M2 = Modified Read Code II (MRII), i.e., fax group 4".

Here is the header that I created :

```
SubFileType (1 Long): Zero
ImageWidth (1 Long): 210
ImageLength (1 Long): 297
BitsPerSample (3 Short): 8, 8, 8
Compression (1 Short): Group 4 Fax (aka CCITT FAX4)
Photometric (1 Short): RGB
StripOffsets (1 Long): 306
SamplesPerPixel (1 Short): 3
RowsPerStrip (1 Short): 297
StripByteCounts (1 Long): 187110
ResolutionUnit (1 Short): None
XResolution (72 Rational): 
YResolution (1 Rational): Unexpected numeric
DateTime (20 ASCII): 2014:07:12 10:51:51 
Software (28 ASCII): Put your software name here 
ImageDescription (30 ASCII): Put an image description here
```

Should I uncompress the image data before merging the header and the image data ?

Comment: provide example TIFF data. how you got TIFF image data.
also provide what you tried.

Comment: With [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/iio-141084.html).

Comment: The TIFF header has been replace by another specific header but the image data bytes are the same. So I skip the header and I got the image data bytes. But I can't figure out how to rebuild the TIFF header.

Comment: No it is exactly the same problem.

Comment: No is is not null and I can read it normally and get the correct length. The doc about ImageIO.read(Inputstream) said that : If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned

Comment: If it's an uncompressed image, have you tried to just read the bytes into an array and create a `BufferedImage` from that? If not, how is the data compressed? Do you know dimensions, color model etc of the image?

Comment: The image is compressed and I can know the compression method (as "M2" for example). I can also know the dimensions, the size of frame (Height and width), the number of line by frame (height and width) and the frame location (X and Y) but I can't know the color model. Do you know a way to uncompress the image data ?

Comment: "M2" isn't a [TIFF compression type](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html) I know of... So, no. It's unclear from the question whether the file contains a valid TIFF prepended with an additional header, or if the TIFF header has been replaced. Is there a reason why you can't provide a sample file?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't provide you a sample file because it is for a company's project and it is private. The TIFF header has been totally replaced.Thank you a lot for your help but I'll understand if you can't help me more thant that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This isn't a fully working example (I would need some sample files to verify in that case), but rather outlines the idea.

First, open a stream to the file, and skip the proprietary header (your code assumes that you can always skip as many bytes you like, but that's not always the case):

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);

int toSkip = 252;
int skipped = 0;

while (toSkip > 0 && (skipped = is.skip(toSkip)) >= 0) {
    toSkip -= skipped;
}
```

Then, re-create a valid, minimal TIFF header, according to the [TIFF specification](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf). This is actually not too hard:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(bytes);

dataOut.write('M');
dataOut.write('M');     // "Motorola" (network) byte order
dataOut.writeShort(42); // TIFF magic identifier (42)

dataOut.writeUnsignedInt(8); // Offset to 1st IFD

// ... write IFD, containing minimal info as per the spec
```

As your input data seems to be in bilevel or black/white fax format (ref. comments), see Section 3: Bilevel Images (page 17) in the spec for the required fields and allowed values. For normal RGB images, see Section 6: RGB Full Color Images (page 24).

Note that SHORT in the spec is (unsigned) `short` in Java, but LONG is (unsigned) `int`. Also note that fields must be written in increasing tag order. RATIONAL can be written as two LONGs (i.e., two unsigned `int`s). For `XResolution` and `YResolution`, just write 72/1 as this is default 72 DPI. `StripOffsets` will be the length of the IFD + 8 for the bytes written before the IFD. If you don't have strips, set `RowsPerStrip` equal to `ImageLength` and `StripByteCounts` equal to the length of the entire (compressed) image data.

When done encoding the header, merge the header and the image data, and read it:

```
ByteArrayInputStream header = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray());
InputStream stream = new SequenceInputStream(header, is); // Merge header and image data
```

Now, you could read the image:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream); // Read image

// TODO: Test that image is non-null before attempting to write
```

However, if you are only writing the TIFF back to a file, you could just copy the data from `stream` to a new file, and try to open it in an external tool. This approach will be much faster and require less memory than decoding the image in Java, and then encoding it back to TIFF (and doesn't need JAI or other TIFF plugin for ImageIO):

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(...));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;

while ((read = stream.read(buffer) >= 0) {
   os.write(0, read, buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can finally create a TIFF header but I can't see the image. Can you take a look at my edit please ?

Comment: @loulou8284 The `YResolution` value seems bogus (missing denominator part?). Come to think of it, `Compression` "CCITT FAX type 4" only supports bilevel (black/white) data (see TIFF class B in the spec). So either `Compression` or `BitsPerSample` and `Photometric` must be changed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `javax.imageio.ImageIO` read/write operations like this :

```
ImageIO.write(img, "TIFF", new File('fileName'));
```

Or you can use the [Java Advanced Imaging API](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/javax/media/jai-core/).

Comment: [ImageIO doesn't support TIFF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html).

Comment: There is a [project](http://java.net/projects/imageio-ext) which adds TIFF read/write ops. to ImageIO.

Comment: My problem here is to get the "img". I have better explained the situtation in my EDIT

Comment: @EJP ImageIO comes with a few formats built-in, but in theory it can support any format, through [plugins](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#background).

Comment: @harafk I'm aware of that, and I'm also aware of what the page I cited says, which is a list of the actual formats supported by ImageIO in all standard implementations, and which does not include TIFF. That's why I cited it. I'm wondering whether you read it before commenting. What he needs is JAI, as I stated in a other comment, which does support TIFF.

Comment: @EJP You misspelled my name, so I didn't see your comment. The link you provide is very useful, indeed. However, I tried to point out, is that the page states "All implementations [..] *provide* the following [..] plug-ins" (emphasis mine), it does not say "formats not listed below are not supported" like your comment seems to indicate. That's all. Peace. :-)